# WindowsError in pathos.multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dill, pathos

```
import subprocess
import os
import dill
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

def main(processes):
    list_of_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    pool = mp.ProcessingPool(processes)
    pool.map(subprocess.call, [['program.exe',fname] 
        for fname in list_of_files])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = 12
    main(processes)
```

Running the above gives the following error:

```
In [1]: %run batch.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\3dns\v3.8\batch.py in <module>()
     26     processes = 12
---> 27     main(processes) 

c:\3dns\v3.8\batch.py in main(cores)
     19
---> 20     pool = mp.ProcessingPool(processes)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pathos-0.2a1.dev0-py2.7.egg\pathos\multiprocessing
.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwds)
     97
     98         # Create a new server if one isn't already initialized
---> 99         self._serve()
    100         return
    101     __init__.__doc__ = AbstractWorkerPool.__init__.__doc__ + __init__.__
doc__

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pathos-0.2a1.dev0-py2.7.egg\pathos\multiprocessing
.pyc in _serve(self, nodes)
    108         _pool = __STATE['pool']
    109         if not _pool or nodes != _pool.__nodes:
--> 110             _pool = Pool(nodes)
    111             _pool.__nodes = nodes
    112             __STATE['pool'] = _pool

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\process
ing\pool.pyc in __init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
     70     '''
     71     def __init__(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=()):
---> 72         self._inqueue = SimpleQueue()
     73         self._outqueue = SimpleQueue()
     74         self._taskqueue = Queue.Queue()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\process
ing\queue.pyc in __init__(self)
    302
    303     def __init__(self):
--> 304         reader, writer = Pipe(duplex=False)
    305         if sys.platform == 'win32':
    306             state = reader, writer, Lock(), None

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\process
ing\__init__.pyc in Pipe(duplex)
     95     '''
     96     from processing.connection import Pipe
---> 97     return Pipe(duplex)
     98
     99 def cpuCount():

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\process
ing\connection.pyc in Pipe(duplex)
    230             win32.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |
    231             win32.PIPE_WAIT,
--> 232             1, obsize, ibsize, win32.NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER, win32.NULL
    233             )
    234         h2 = win32.CreateFile(

WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

This was on a Windows 7 64-bit machine in the interactive IPython console (Anaconda Distribution of Python 2.7). I'm using pathos version 0.2a1.dev0 and Dill version 0.2.2. This error seems to be reproducible when ever I create a 'Pool'.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like a  known bug in the underlying `processing` library when running on 64-bit Windows: pathos issue [#49](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/49) on GitHub.

Have you tried using the Python `multiprocessing` library directly? It worked reliably for me on Windows when I used it last, although I don't have a Windows machine to hand to test specific behaviors at the moment.

Comment: This specific example works when I use the `multiprocessing` library directly but I need `pathos.multiprocessing` for a certain task since `multiprocessing` gives a pickling error for that task.

Comment: Windows doesn't let child processes inherit resources directly from parents; Python works around this by pickling the objects and communicating them at child process creation time. If you know what object is causing the pickling failure, often you can work around this by passing i.e. constructor arguments to the child and recreating it there.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author. I'd probably agree with @WillAngley on his diagnosis of the cause.  If you want to detect what's causing the pickling error, try some of the functions in `dill.detect`, and specifically turn on `dill.detect.trace(True)`.  I think I there might be a workaround if it'd be possible to pickle whatever is causing the issue by reference (which `dill` doesn't do by default).  I need to expose that serialization option to `pathos` -- that is also already is a ticket.

Comment: I re-installed `pathos` and still got the same error when I use `pathos.multirpocessing.Core`. But if I use `pathos.pp.ParallelProcessingPool`, the example code (from the `pathos` site) works. I was unable to use it for my code though; it seems the `dill` was also unable to pickle a portion of the code. At this point, though, it may be simpler to run my program on a single core. Anyway, thanks for the prompt responses.

Comment: @wye_naught: First off, there is no `pathos.multiprocessing.Core`… maybe you mean `pathos.core`?  Regardless, please feel free to share what bugs or missing features you found.  That's the only way they can be patched/added.

Comment: Sorry...I meant to type `pathos.multiprocessing.Pool`. It's probably the same ticket on github as you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the `pathos` author.  Indeed, it was @WillAngley suggested.  The bug is now fixed.  i have verified on windows 8.1, python 2.7, and with pathos and associated dependencies also in master or most recent release for 3-rd party.  The critical issue was updating the fork of `multiprocessing`.  This is done, and in a new package called `multiprocess`.